# Mapped type on methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to make an object type that defines values from another type.

I orintally had this:

```
export interface Obj {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

I would now like to change it to contain a list of items from another type. I tried the following but I am getting an error:

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

```
type ListOfMethods = {
  one(): void
  two(): void
}

export interface Obj {
  [key: keyof ListOfMethods]: any
}
```

So with that error I tried this:

```
[key in keyof ListOfMethods]: any
```

And now get this error

> A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.

Comment: `type = ListOfMethods` must be `type ListOfMethods` :)

Comment: Fixed, that was a typo :)

Comment: In the actual code the `ListOfMethods` type is just a list of events passed to `addEventListener`, where the name is the key and the function is the event, so if there is a built in way to list those names as functions... that would be nice...

Comment: `type names = "one" | "two" | "three";` and then `{[key in names]: () => void}`

Comment: @JonasW. is this correct? `export interface Obj {[key in names]: () => void}`? If so I am getting an error: `'Obj' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define `Obj` as:

```
export type Obj = {
  [key in keyof ListOfMethods]: any
}
```

If you use `:` you are indicating the type of the key, and the type of a key can only be `number` or `string`.

`keyof` creates a subtype of `string` that only admits the values in that are properties of the argument object. In this case, `keyof ListOfMethods` is `'one' | 'two'`.